# SQL query to show spending history

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been asked to create a query that makes a debtors spend history table.

Data source: MYOB Exonet
There are parent accounts, but the table is to be of child accounts. However, child account transactions don't actually transact at child level - they do so at parent level. But I want only some of the child accounts to be reported.

Tables are as follows:
`DR_ACCS (debtor accounts)`

There is a 'view' which gives the transactions for the child accounts. It does not appear in the database, but when entering a query, it comes up as

`AnaylticsSalesInvoices`

The join between `DR_ACCS` and `AnalyticsSalesInvoices` is `DR_ACCS.ACCNO = AnalyticsSalesInvoices.accountNumberAnalysis`.

So, Now i need to go "get all the transactions for accounts who have the field `DR_ACCS.X_TOPCUSTOMER` ticked `'Y'`, and split them into 'this month' 'last month' '2 months ago' and 'last 12 months'."

What I want is a result like this:

```
> Customer Name | This Month | Last Month | 2 Months Ago | 12 Month |    
> Jones         |       $235 |       $756 |          $49 |    $2800 |   
> Smith         |        $14 |         $0 |         $459 |     $629 |  
> Lewis         |       $520 |        $35 |           $0 |    $9206 |
```

Can anyone assist with this? I have tried various ways and got well lost!

Comment: What are the columns on each table?

Comment: Sorry, I've looked in deeper, and I don't think we even need the `DR_TRANS` table at all.

Comment: OK, `DR_ACCS.ACCNO (pk, int, not null)` `DR_ACCS.NAME (varchar(40,null)` `DR_ACCS.X_TOPCUSTOMER (char(1),null)` and `DR_ACCS.MONTHVAL (float,null)` are the fields from DR_ACCS. then in the other table (which I can't seem to find in the database because it's a 'view' :    `AnalyticsSalesInvoices.AccountNameAnalysis (int,not null)` `AnalyticsSalesInvoices.SalesValueTaxExclusive (float,null)`  and `AnalyticsSalesInvoices.TransactionDate (date)`

Comment: So, if the DR_ACCS.X_TOPCUSTOMER feild is 'Y' then Add up the SalesValueTaxExclusive for this month, again for last month, again for the month before, and again for the last 12 consecutive months.

Comment: The issue I've hit so far is if the value is empty, it doesn't return $0.00, so the results are all over the show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE
    @this_start DATETIME,
    @this_end   DATETIME,
    @last_start DATETIME,
    @last_end   DATETIME,
    @l2_start   DATETIME,
    @l2_end     DATETIME,
    @year_start DATETIME,
    @year_end   DATETIME

SELECT
    @this_start = DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0),
    @this_end   = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)),
    @last_start = DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),
    @last_end   = DATEADD(s,-1,@this_start),
    @l2_start   = DATEADD(m,-2,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),
    @l2_end     = DATEADD(s,-1,@last_start),
    @year_start = DATEADD(m,-12,@this_start),
    @year_end   = @this_end

-- just a check of the variable values:
SELECT              -- GETDATE() = 2014-09-15 10:50:15.000
    @this_start,    -- 2014-09-01 00:00:00.000
    @this_end,      -- 2014-09-30 23:59:59.000
    @last_start,    -- 2014-08-01 00:00:00.000
    @last_end,      -- 2014-08-31 23:59:59.000
    @l2_start,      -- 2014-07-01 00:00:00.000
    @l2_end,        -- 2014-07-31 23:59:59.000
    @year_start,    -- 2013-09-01 00:00:00.000
    @year_end       -- 2014-09-30 23:59:59.000

SELECT 
    dr_accs.NAME,
    [This Month]   = SUM(CASE WHEN b.date BETWEEN @this_start AND @this_end THEN b.total ELSE 0 END),
    [Last Month]   = SUM(CASE WHEN b.date BETWEEN @last_start AND @last_end THEN b.total ELSE 0 END),
    [2 Months Ago] = SUM(CASE WHEN b.date BETWEEN @l2_start AND @l2_end THEN b.total ELSE 0 END),
    [12 Month]     = SUM(b.total)

FROM dr_accs JOIN AnalyticsSalesInvoices b ON DR_ACCS.ACCNO = b.accountNumberAnalysis
WHERE dr_accs.x_topcustomer = 'Y'
AND b.date_field BETWEEN @year_start AND @year_end
```

Please note that you will have to change 'b.date' and 'b.total' to your actual column names.